# How do you redeem the mini-Thor WoW pet that comes with the StarCraft II Collector's Edition?

Tags: starcraft-2, world-of-warcraft, battle.net

One of the advertised extra items that comes with the Collector's Edition of *StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty* is an "exclusive in-game *World of Warcraft* pet" ([full list](http://us.starcraft2.com/features/collector/)).  However, I didn't see anything about this inside the Collector's Edition box.

How do you redeem the WoW pet?  Is it something that's automatically associated with your Battle.net account when you register your SC2:CE CD key?  I don't play WoW, but I'm curious.  Is it possible for me to give away the pet to someone else who plays WoW, or is it permanently attached to my Battle.net account?  Or am I just being blind and there actually was a code inside the box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pet is automatically associated with your Battle.net account when you register your StarCraft II Collector's Edition CD Key.  You cannot give it away.

If someday you do decide to play World of Warcraft, you will have a shiny new mini-Thor waiting for you in your mailbox.

It's awesome, by the way.